# Sequelize - The multi-part identifier XXX could not be bound

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I'm trying to run a query with an order option in Sequelize with SQL Server. I've read some examples in SO but I haven't found a solution while running the queries on Sequelize.

```
let order = [["winner","new_apv","asc"]];

 const include = [
    {
      model: Item_Supplier,
      as: "itemSupplier",
      attributes: ["id", "supplierOrderId", "cost"],
      include: [
        {
          model: Supplier,
          as: "supplier"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      model: Winner,
      as: "winner",
      attributes: ["supplierId", "new_apv"],
      include: [
        {
          model: Supplier,
          as: "supplier",
          attributes: ["supplierName"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

 await Item.findAll({include,order})
```

This is the error message

> The multi-part identifier "winner.new_apv" could not be bound.

Here is the SQL Server query Sequelize generates:

```
SELECT [item].*, [itemSupplier].[id] AS 
[itemSupplier.id], [itemSupplier].[supplierOrderId] AS 
[itemSupplier.supplierOrderId], [itemSupplier].[cost] AS 
[itemSupplier.cost], [itemSupplier->supplier].[id] AS 
[itemSupplier.supplier.id], [itemSupplier->supplier].[supplierName] AS 
[itemSupplier.supplier.supplierName], [itemSupplier->supplier].[duns] AS 
[itemSupplier.supplier.duns] 
FROM (SELECT [item].[id], [item].[item_price], [item].[common_code], [item].[uom], [item].[usage_per_item], [item].[apv], 
[item].[impac_commodity], [item].[mfgname], [item].[mtr_grp_desc], [item].[description], [item].[comments], [item].[renewed_2019],
[item].[currency], [item].[contractId], [item].[mtrId], [item].[allocationId], [winner].[id] AS [winner.id], 
[winner].[supplierId]
 AS [winner.supplierId], [winner].[new_apv] 
 AS [winner.new_apv], [winner->supplier].[id]
 AS [winner.supplier.id], [winner->supplier].[supplierName]
 AS [winner.supplier.supplierName] FROM [items] AS [item] 
 INNER JOIN [winners] AS [winner] 
 ON [item].[id] = [winner].[itemId] 
 AND [winner].[deletedAt] IS NULL 
 INNER JOIN [suppliers] AS [winner->supplier] 
 ON [winner].[supplierId] = [winner->supplier].[id]
 WHERE ([item].[deletedAt] IS NULL AND ([item].[contractId] = 4 AND [item].[renewed_2019] LIKE N'YES%'))
 ORDER BY [item].[id] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY) AS [item] LEFT OUTER JOIN [item_suppliers] AS [itemSupplier]
  ON [item].[id] = [itemSupplier].[itemId] AND ([itemSupplier].[deletedAt] IS NULL) LEFT OUTER JOIN [suppliers] 
  AS [itemSupplier->supplier] ON [itemSupplier].[supplierId] = [itemSupplier->supplier].[id] ORDER BY [winner].[new_apv]  ASC;
```

Comment: Does the query works in SSMS? That mean the column `[winner].[new_apv]` can't be found.

Comment: no it doesnt, [winner].[new_apv] is underlined with red and it shows the same error message when i try to run it

Comment: I think [Allow to order findAll() results by attribute on a join table](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3173) is what you're looking for. Take a look at `sherpya`'s answer.

Comment: Thanks, I add the answer

Answer (score 0):

Using Sequelize literal and adding the single quotes in the literal itself did the trick.

```
order = [[Sequelize.literal('"winner.new_apv"'), desc ? "DESC" : "ASC"]];
```